# VARIABLE WIDTH & height linear layout : android

Tags: android, resize, android-linearlayout

I have to resize one of the views or both...
It seems that once `setContentView` has been called a new `setCotentView` cannot be called. I was trying to re size the content by creating again the whole layout.

Please tell me how to do it...

Here is the code I have so far:

```
package v.w;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.graphics.Color;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup.LayoutParams;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.LinearLayout;


public class VariableWidthActivity extends Activity {
    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
    LinearLayout RLGreen;
    LinearLayout RLChange;
    Button btnClick;
    LinearLayout RLYellow ;
    Button  btClick;

        @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        RLChange = new LinearLayout(this);        
        RLChange.setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT,
                                                 LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT)); 
        RLChange.setOrientation(LinearLayout.VERTICAL);

        RLGreen = new LinearLayout(this);        
        RLGreen.setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT,
                                                 LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT));
        RLGreen.setBackgroundColor(Color.GREEN);
        RLGreen.setOrientation(LinearLayout.HORIZONTAL);
        btnClick = new Button(this);        
        btnClick.setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
                LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT) );
        //btnClick.setBackgroundColor(Color.RED);
        btnClick.setText("BUTTON");


        RLYellow = new LinearLayout(this);        
        RLYellow.setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT,
                                                 200));
        RLYellow.setBackgroundColor(Color.YELLOW);
        RLChange.addView(RLGreen);
        RLGreen.addView(RLYellow);

        RLGreen.addView(btnClick);


    }
        @Override
        protected void onResume() {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            super.onResume();

            setContentView(RLChange);
            btClick=new Button(this);
            btClick.setText("BUTTON");
            btClick.setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
                    LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT) );
            //btnClick.setBackgroundColor(Color.RED);
            RLYellow.addView(btClick);
            btClick.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

                public void onClick(View view) { 
                    //RLChange.forceLayout();
                    RLChange.removeAllViews();

                    RLChange.addView(RLYellow);
                    RLChange.addView(RLGreen);
                    RLGreen.addView(btnClick);
                    setContentView(RLChange);
                }
             });  

        }

}
```

Comment: Why are you doing this in code and not in an XML layout?

Comment: The `setContentView` method should only be called once an activity and in onCreate.  Can you explain why you're trying to refresh the entire layout, and maybe someone will be able to point you towards an alternate method.